# Dew Audio player not working in blogger

Tags: flash, audio, blogs, web-platforms

I have an mp3 file in google sites and I want to play that file using Dew player.
I have used the below code

```html
<object align="right" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/dewplayer-mini.swf" width="160" height="20" border="0" id="dewplayer" name="dewplayer"> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="Movie" value="/dewplayer-mini.swf"/> 
<param name="flashvars" value="mp3=test.mp3"/> 
</object>
```

but it doesn't work. Why is that and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the link to your mp3 at the `value="mp3=..."`.
 Where you replace `...` with your **direct** URL/path link.

What do you have to put in browser address bar to hear the mp3 file only? That is your direct URL (or path) to file. If not sure then, show us a link to your page and say what the file name is called.

For example :

```
<object align="right" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/dewplayer-mini.swf" width="160" height="20" border="0" id="dewplayer" name="dewplayer"> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="Movie" value="/dewplayer-mini.swf"/> 
<param name="flashvars" value="mp3=http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile.mp3"/> 
</object>
```

Comment: I have tried above your mention code, but I brought the domain form Godaddy to mapped with my blogger website after that not playing mp3, Domain Mapping before it's working the player now only this problem please give a solution for this problem

Comment: Can you provide a testable mp3 link from your site? You can deIete later since just for testing now. PS: I don't think the mapping should affect mp3 playback. If concerned, then just show me a link to your page with DewPlayer & I will check to provide a solution.